# can iceweasel automatically go "back" when it loads an error page

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, web.py

short version:
I am making a web kiosk that loads only one site. I want the browser to automatically go "back" (return to previous page) when it gets an error on the page it is loading. is this possible if so how would i make it work?

long version:
i am making a webpy program that accesses a WSDL. the webpy program is accessed from a raspberry pi set up to function as a touch kiosk. the user will not have access to a back button. i check to see if the WSDL is up and running when the program starts and when a user logs on. i do not check on every call to the WSDL because i worry the bandwidth might get overwhelming as i add users (100+). my fear is if the WSDL goes down after log in, iceweasel will load an error (404?) page and strand the user on that page.   any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try making yourself a [custom webpy error page](http://webpy.org/cookbook/custom_notfound) that simply redirects the user back to the main page (probably using JavaScript). In your code.py:
`def notfound():
    return web.notfound("<script>window.location="http://some.com";<script>")`